First Time pushing React Project to Github and terminal gives me error
So I'm pushing this react project into a github repository. Right after my terminal is done uploading all the files it throws me this error about my HomePageVid.mp4 being too big.
hari@Haris-MacBook-Air videos % git push -u origin main
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (16/16), 268 MB | 0 B/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 107, done.
Counting objects: 100% (107/107), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (106/106), done.
Writing objects: 100% (107/107), 255.45 MiB | 15.55 MiB/s, done.
Total 107 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: error: Trace: 15ff7c47b4bb7fd8350b6046aa93210056bf31d0b4f8b992ad4e99fb94e5b529
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File public/videos/HomePageVid.mp4 is 229.06 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/haristeelers/travel-blog.git
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/haristeelers/travel-blog.git'
I already installed Git Large File Storage and tracked my mp4 and jpg files. Even after that it throws me this error. So I deleted my old repository and made a new one with a similar name. Then I reset the origin to the new url. I also tried tracking the individual files but it still gives me this error. There's probably a lot of mistakes I made since it's my first time. I just want to know the next steps in resolving this error.

I figured it out!
